# How can I set the 'markerStyle' to 'selected' in jVectorMap when the page opens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

[This is an example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vinko_k_design/V8dyd/214/)

I am trying to have a marker already selected on the map as soon as the page loads.

is there a way to add the `selected` state defined in `markerStyle` to the markers:

```
var markerArray = [
    {name:'Houston', latLng:[29.761993,-95.369568]},
    {name:'New York', latLng:[40.710833,-74.002533]},
    {name:'Kansas City', latLng:[39.115145,-94.633484]}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selectedMarkers options for that. For example the following snippet will make the first and the second markers to be selected on load:

```
selectedMarkers: [0,1]
```